# localhost:8080/greeting does not respond

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to make an example for the REST service from

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I have created all the 3 classes

[image: Package explorer view]

I am sharing the code. I have seen the other question where there was a problem with the different packages but my classes are in the same package.

[image: Application Class]

[image: GreetingController Class]

[image: Greeting Class]

After i run the program i get the following result:

[image: Console]

I see that the console says terminated so i do not know if this is the reason why i can not access the localhost:8080/greeting and i get that the site can't be reached

[image: Site Err]

This project is built from Spring Tool 4 cause in Eclipse i get an error when i try to select from Projects the "Import Spring Getting Started Content", but this is a second problem.

[image]

The console gives the next:

```html
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

2018-11-12 19:03:36.968  INFO 20324 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on ACL_GRE_PavlidisK with PID 20324 (C:\Users\KyriakosP\WorkSpaces\SpringTool\gs-consuming-rest-initial\target\classes started by KyriakosP in C:\Users\KyriakosP\WorkSpaces\SpringTool\gs-consuming-rest-initial)
2018-11-12 19:03:36.968  INFO 20324 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-12 19:03:37.015  INFO 20324 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@21a947fe: startup date [Mon Nov 12 19:03:37 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-11-12 19:03:37.701  INFO 20324 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-11-12 19:03:37.705  INFO 20324 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 0.991 seconds (JVM running for 1.338)
2018-11-12 19:03:37.705  INFO 20324 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@21a947fe: startup date [Mon Nov 12 19:03:37 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-11-12 19:03:37.705  INFO 20324 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- 
plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-consuming-rest'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-web")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

I haven't changed the gradle file. There is nothing in the tutorial about Gradle file

After your proposal to add

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
```

on gradle file when i run the application from IDE the program is terminated.

The same with maven from command.

Only gradle (gradle bootRun) from command line works and keeps running so the browser responses. SO what it is killing the app in these cases?

Comment: What happens when you run through command line? e.g `./gradlew bootRun`

Comment: Even with gradlew and with maven it downloads some files and there is the same output as i attached.

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong with your code, so I would suggest trying different ways of running that the tutorial lists in the building an executable jar section

Comment: do you see the /greeting being mapped in the startup logs. Also can you add your gradle file to see the dependencies?

Comment: i have added the console response. I do not understand why someone need to give a -1 rating

Comment: i donot see the /greeting getting mapped. Please add your gradle file as well. Also remove the error about eclipse that not related to the question maybe thats why someone downvoted.

Comment: i have added tha gradle file. i feel that downvoted based on eclipse is like someones tries to find reason to downvote.

Comment: check the gradle in the tutorial i think you need to add compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"). Just click on build with gradle

Comment: I added the gradle to my answer try that.

Comment: i have added the starter web. From cmd with gradle it works and the browser works. From cmd and maven it does not work. From spring tools running the program as Java application or Spring-Boot-Application it does not work also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183511/discussion-between-kyrpav-and-grinish-nepal).

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- 
plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-consuming-rest'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Also as spring boot document says you should locate you main application class in the root package above other class. Just a thought for you to work on.

This is the official spring boot doc:- 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Comment: You can write a whole application in the same package even within the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to specify what method of RequestMethod it is:

e.g.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

or

```
 @GetMapping("/greeting")
```

other than that it look sok to me.

You might want to look if you have the web starter in your build.gradle file.

Example in one file `DemoGradleApplication`:

```
package com.example.demogradle;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.UUID;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoGradleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoGradleApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Message helloWorld() {
        return new Message(UUID.randomUUID()
                               .toString(), "Hello, world!");
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello/{id:.*$}")
    public Message hello(@PathVariable("id") String msg) {
        return new Message(UUID.randomUUID()
                               .toString(), msg);
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Message {

    private String id;
    private String message;
}
```

with gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Run with:

```
gradlew bootRun
```

Goto url `http://localhost:8080/hello` or `http://localhost:8080/hello/you all rocking people` in a browser

Comment: In the build.gradle for dependencies there is dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-web")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

Comment: A you see no web starter so no web possibilities.

Comment: For the @RequestMapping("/greeting") they say in the tutorial that it covers all methods

Comment: It is still better to be explicit in java then implicit :-)

Comment: I have to say that i did not change the gradle file this is the example of the site.